# Find and remove consecutive duplicated words while ignoring case

Tags: regular-expressions, query-replace, words

I am trying to find and remove duplicated words in a LaTeX file.

Right now I am using `query-replace-regexp` with the regular expression
`\b\(\w+\)[ #]+\1` where `#` stands for line-break (`C-q C-j`). This does not ignore case, however, and misses the following repetition of the word 'the':

```
I am the new organ player. The the new keymaster.
```

Are regular expressions sufficient for this or it's better
to program a lisp function to go word by word, checking whether consecutive words are the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can `query-replace-regexp` as follows:

```
\(\b\w+\b\)\W+\1\b → \1
```

This means, match a whole word (`\b\w+\b`), followed by non word characters (`\W+`), followed by the first word (`\1`) and a word ending (`\b`). Replace with the first word only.

Case sensitivity is handled by options `case-fold-search` and `case-replace`.